# Create a table of 400 specific value and be able to retrieve data from it - in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a table of  20 value of x and 20 value of y (400 input) which I would populate each input with different value. (Its a chart that provide the equivalent temperature when T = a specific degree but Humidity is = xx.x%

I would like to create the table and then be able to read from it

Ex: Temp = 25 Degree Celcius
    Humidity = 80 %

The value in the table at 25 degree(y) and 80 %(x) is 33 Degree Celsius

I am new with Python. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: `25 + 80 = 33` how exactly? clearly this is domain specific knowledge .. we have no idea how this maps

Comment: [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/). Or maybe pandas.

Answer (score 1):

## Basic idea, implemented with Python nested lists

It seems that you want a two-dimensional lookup table. This is easily implemented in Python using nested lists. For instance, suppose you want to encode a 3x3 table of quotients, such that the quotient N/M is in the (N-1)th row and (M-1)th column (using Python's 0-based indexing):

```
1.00 0.50 0.33
2.00 1.00 0.66
3.00 1.50 1.00
```

You could write this table as `[[1.00,0.50,0.33],[2.00,1.00,0.67],[3.00,1.50,1.00]]`, and look up using two indices (row first, then column):

```
look_up_table = [[1.00,0.50,0.33],[2.00,1.00,0.67],[3.00,1.50,1.00]]
two_over_three = look_up_table[1][2]
```

## Numpy

If you plan to do any computations using the resulting matrix, Numpy is the way to go.

```
import numpy as np
look_up_table = np.zeros((3,3))
for m in range(3):
    for n in range(3):
        look_up_table[m,n] = float(m+1)/float(n+1)
```

Now for instance, if you wanted the lookup to work backwards, e.g. a/b = lookup_table[b-1][a-1], you could simply do `lookup_table = 1.0/lookup_table`.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just to manually store your data and be able to read it, you could easily use a dictionary. For your key, you could use a tuple of the temp and humidity like this :

```
data = {}
data[25,80] = 33
```

Now, if you do `data[25,80]`, it will return you `33`